# How to have a small select bar but a bigger option body,jquery ui ,multiselect

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-ui

I am using jquery ui with multiselect, I need a very small select bar(as small as possible), but when it opens, the body will be large enough to hold the items.

As the screenshot shows, I have two problem:

1. The select bar is not small enough, though I set `minWidth =1`
2. The body is too small to hold the items.

Do I have a quick way to solve my problems? Thank you!

```
$handler.multiselect({
    multiple: true,
    header: null,
    minWidth: 1//I set it to 1, but it is not small enough , the the body is too small
```

...

[image: problem]

My code now is like

Comment: can you reproduce the issue in jsfiddle.net? ... override multiselect css? which `multiselect` plugin do you use?

Comment: what he said, there are literally hundreds.